# Handle Socket Exception and Other Exception with Apache CXF Client

Tags: web-services, apache, cxf

How can I capture socket exceptions i.e network connectivity errors in Apache cxf client so that I can proceed ahead with another logic when exceptions are captured. I have web service with socket time out with 3 secs and it works properly. Socket Timeout exceptions cannot be captured with JaxWsProxyFactoryBean. When time out occurs, I need to notify my application that there is network connectivity failures ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to catch any javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException